# Dynamic tuple in Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I obtained data with tuple in pig

```
   0,(0),(zero)
   1,(1,2),(first,second)
```

Can I receive this?

```
   0,0,zero
   1,1,first
   1,2,second
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I created UDF with dynamic tuples.

Answer (score 0):

To start off, I'm going to correct your terminology and you should be treating `(0)` and `(1,2)` as bags, not tuples. Tuples are intended to be fixed-length data structures that represent some sort of entity. Say `(name, address, year of birth)`, for example. If you have a list of similar objects, like `{(apple), (orange), (banana)}`, you want a bag.

---

There doesn't exist behavior that allows you to "zip" up multiple bags/lists. The reason for this is from a design perspective, Pig treats bags as *unordered* lists, hence the term "bag" not "list". This assumption really helps out with parallelism since you don't have to be considered with order. Therefore, it's really hard to match up `1` with `first`.

---

What you could try to do is write an [eval function UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/udf.html#eval-functions) that takes in two bags as parameters, and then zips up the two lists, and then returns back one back with the bags zipped.

Comment: Couldn't you get output like this from `STRSPLIT`, for example?

Comment: He could generate the individual bags with `STRSPLIT`, but you still need to zip them.

Comment: But `STRSPLIT` returns a tuple. Doing something like `STRSPLIT($0, ':')` on data where `$0` is `zero` and `first:second` should produce what the OP is talking about.

Comment: @mr2ert you should post an answer, I'd be interested in seeing more clearly what you are talking about.

Comment: Can I use FOREACH t3 GENERATE col1, col2.$0, col3.$0; and UNION 
FOREACH t3 GENERATE col1, col2.$1, col3.$1; 
?